# SWF content on iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, ffmpeg, flash

Can I play/parse SWF content on the iPhone using FFMPEG? As per the [document](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) it should support ShockWave Flash (SWF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg can (sometimes) play video and audio files embeded in swf file. It cannot play the swf file itself.